# How to create remote file node for contentful image

Tags: gatsby, contentful, gatsby-image

I am looking for help. I create a blog in gatsby using contentful.
I would like the photos in posts to use gatsby-plugin-sharp and gatsby-image. If I understand correctly, I have to use createRemoteFileNode from the gatsby-source-filesystem plugin. But I have a problem because I think I have a mistake. Below is my code that adds to the gatsby-node file.

```
const { createRemoteFileNode } = require('gatsby-source-filesystem')

module.exports.downloadMediaFiles = ({ nodes, store, cache, createNode, createNodeId, _auth }) => {
  nodes.map(async node => {
    let fileNode

    if (node.internal.type === 'ContentfulAsset') {
      try {
        fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
          url: node.source_url,
          parentNodeId: node.id,
          store,
          cache,
          createNode,
          createNodeId,
          auth: _auth,
        })
      } catch (e) {
        // Ignore
      }
    }

    if (fileNode) {
      node.localFile___NODE = fileNode.id
    }
  })
}
```

I am asking for help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you have a mistake? Provide an error message and expected output, and also tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: are you using `gatsby-source-conntentful` ?